# matches between first and second order logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is common matches between first order logic and the second order logic?
in other word what in first order logic is in second order logic?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged under [fuzzy-logic]. Is this related, in any way to fuzzy logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every sentence in first-order predicate logic is also a sentence in second-order predicate logic. (Assuming the langues are compatible, i.e. you have the same predicate and function symbols, of course).

And if it's provable in first-order predicate logic, it's provable in second-order predicate logic. (Now assuming the languages are compatible, and the axioms you use in second-order predicate logic are a superset of the one in first-order predicate logic, of course).

The converse is *not* true, i.e. second-order predicate logic is (way!) more powerfull than first-order predicate logic. You can, for example, uniquely define the integers in second-order predicate logic, but you cannot do so in first-order predicate logic.